How is an Array made Identifiable in SwiftUI?
I'm new at Swift/SwitUI and trying to learn how to use an overlay over a Chart Content.  I found some code on Apple's Developer but it didn't show how the Array 'data' was coded.  I The code is below but it failed to compile returning the error "Type '(date: Date, price: Double)' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'".
I've found some examples for other data types but I've not been able to make them work. An answer to a somewhat similar question suggested sorting the dictionary and Xcode suggested that I use this:
Chart(data.sorted(by: <#T##((date: Date, price: Double), (date: Date, price: Double)) throws -> Bool#>))
but I get the same error.
    import SwiftUI
    import Charts
    
    struct ContentView: View {
    
      @State private var data: [(date: Date, price: Double)] = [
        (Date(), 100.0),
        (Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), 120.0),
        (Date().addingTimeInterval(2 * 86400), 90.0),
        (Date().addingTimeInterval(3 * 86400), 85.0),
        (Date().addingTimeInterval(4 * 86400), 100.0) ]
        
        var body: some View {
        VStack {
           // starting here: from Apple' Developer ...
           // ERROR HERE: "Type '(date: Date, price: Double)' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'"
           Chart(data) {
             LineMark(
        x: .value("date", $0.date),
        y: .value("price", $0.price)
         )
    }
    .chartOverlay { proxy in
        GeometryReader { geometry in
        Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
            .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                let origin = geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin
                let location = CGPoint(
                    x: value.location.x - origin.x,
                    y: value.location.y - origin.y
                )
                let (date, price) = proxy.value(at: location, as: (Date, Double).self)!
                print("Location: \(date), \(price)")
                }
            )
            }
           }
            }.padding()
        }
    }



That is an array of a  tuple not a dictionary, if you get rid of the parenthesis and replace the comma for a colon you will have a dictionary.

Each item that you pass to the Chart needs to be Identifiable. (date: Date, price: Double) isn't Identifiable. If your data is unique by date, you can pass an id: \.0 to your Chart initializer.

@loremipsum I've corrected the question.

read this doc:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/creating-a-chart-using-swift-charts  especially the struct ToyShape: Identifiable

Try this approach using a struct DataItem: Identifiable to make each DataItem uniquely identifiable in the array, and to hold your data
to be displayed, as shown in the example code.
Note, you make the elements of the array Identifiable, not the Array itself.
struct DataItem: Identifiable {  // <-- here
    let id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var price: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // -- here
    let data = [DataItem(date: Date(), price: 100.0),
                DataItem(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), price: 120.0),
                DataItem(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(2 * 86400), price: 90.0),
                DataItem(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(3 * 86400), price: 85.0),
                DataItem(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(4 * 86400), price: 100.0)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(data) {
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("date", $0.date),
                    y: .value("price", $0.price)
                )
            }
            .chartOverlay { proxy in
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    let origin = geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin
                                    let location = CGPoint(
                                        x: value.location.x - origin.x,
                                        y: value.location.y - origin.y
                                    )
                                    let (date, price) = proxy.value(at: location, as: (Date, Double).self)!
                                    print("Location: \(date), \(price)")
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

